# NSIS registers state

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I am using NSIS for my installer and uninstaller

In the Installer i am using $R3 to store some string.

Will the string still be available from $R3 at Uninstall? Can I use it again at the Uninstaller?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, any state you need in the uninstaller has to be stored in the registry or a .ini file by the installer an read back in uninstaller (in `un.onInit` etc)